Showing there is always rational points on the curve $\sqrt{x^2-1}$, with any given range
Can I prove that there is always such rational number $x\in(a,b)$ that makes $$\sqrt{x^2-1}$$ also rational, with any given real numbers $1\leq a<b$? I tried intermediate value theorem, but then I couldn't show $x$ was rational.
Or please let me know what mathematicians call property like this(existence of rational points with any given range on the curve), if there is the name. Thank you for all your helps.

This amounts to asking whether rational points are dense on the unit circle. They are.

@EricTowers Sorry for my English. I don't understand what do you mean by the domain. The domain of the function is $(1,\inf)$ and x is always in an open interval $(a,b)$. As I know, rationals are dense in every open interval of real line. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong

@GerryMyerson Isn't the unit circle $\sqrt{1-x^2}$? Or are they the same ultimately? Besides, if you have the proof that rational points are dense on the unit circle, please let me know where it is. I think it would be helpful.

$y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, $y^2=x^2-1$, $(s/t)^2+1=(r/t)^2$, $(s/r)^2+(t/r)^2=1$. $1<x<\infty$ iff $0<(t/r)<1$. Density of rationals on the unit circle, probably done on this website several times already – basic idea, any line through $(1,0)$ with rational slope hits circle at a rational point.

@오연우 I guess you can find something useful from this blog: https://grossack.site/2021/11/16/dense-pythagorean-triples.html.  The author seems to discuss a similar problem.

Here is a proof based on Gerry Myerson's comments:
Let's begin with the easy part: if $x=\frac{q^2+1}{q^2-1}$, where $q$ is a rational number greater than $1$, then both $x$ and $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{2q}{q^2-1}$ are rational numbers.
Now we have to show that there exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
a<\frac{q^2+1}{q^2-1}<b. \tag{1}
$$
Without loss of generality, let's assume that $a>1$ (if $a=1$, replace $a$ with $a':=\frac{a+b}{2}>1$ in the argument below). Then we may rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
\frac{b+1}{b-1}<q^2<\frac{a+1}{a-1}. \tag{2}
$$
Notice that the interval $\left(\frac{b+1}{b-1},\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)$ is non-empty, for
$$
\frac{a+1}{a-1}-\frac{b+1}{b-1}=\frac{2(b-a)}{(a-1)(b-1)}>0. \tag{3}
$$
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$
1<\sqrt{\frac{b+1}{b-1}}<q<\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}. \tag{4}
$$
$(4)$ implies $(1)$ via $(2)$. This completes the proof.
